# how to combine three tables in one query an i need all the rows?

Tags: php, mysql

```
//( ! ) Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

No idea getting this problem. Please guys help me out. Here is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT t1.employeecode, t1.employeename, t2.v, t2.w, t3.total, t3.totals
                FROM invoice t1,salaries t2,table1 t3
                WHERE t1.employeecode = salaries.employeecode AND
                t1.employeecode = t3.employeecode
                ORDER BY t1.employeecode ASC";

    $result = mysql_query($query,$con);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){

        echo '<table><tr><th>Article title</th>&nbsp;</tr>';
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            //$postedon = strftime("%A %e %b %Y",strtotime($row['postedon']));
            echo '<h1><tr><td><a href="3.php?employeecode='.$row["employeecode"].'">'.$row["deparment"].'</a></td></tr></h1>';
        }
```

Comment: Check the error with `mysql_query($con)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: Your `mysql_query()` fails and returns `FALSE`. Make sure your `SELECT` works in mysql or any other IDE (e.g. phpmyadmin) you're using

Comment: what is the structure of your tables please provide foreign_keys and use joins

Answer (score 2):

$result is boolean (false) cause there must be problem with your query. Help yourself by getting error in your query using `mysql_error()`,

```
$result = mysql_query($query,$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

**Note**: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation).

So use either [`PDO`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/1723893) or `MySQLi` (IMO PDO is way to go)

Comment: I got the result. But in that i ve created a 2 different profiles for each person. but i'm getting a same profile details for both the person. eg: sam & john are having different profile details. But when i open sam's profile detail it's showing john's profile detail. Actually its showing a single details in every different profile.     Help me guys.

Answer (score 2):

Since you aliased your `salaries` table to `t2` you have to reference it as `t2` in your where clause:

```
$query = "SELECT t1.employeecode, t1.employeename, t2.v, t2.w, t3.total,
            t3.totals
            FROM invoice t1,salaries t2,table1 t3
            WHERE t1.employeecode = t2.employeecode AND
            t2.employeecode = t3.employeecode
            ORDER BY t1.employeecode ASC";
```

Comment: I got the result. But in that i ve created a 2 different profiles for each person. but i'm getting a same profile details for both the person. eg: sam & john are having different profile details. But when i open sam's profile detail it's showing john's profile detail. Actually its showing a single details in every different profile. Help me.

Comment: @RahulKumar the employeecode will be different for 2 profile. check employeecode. May be it's same for 2 profiles you are passing.

Comment: @ripa the employeecode is different only in both the profile. actually i ve given "PRIMARY KEY" to employeecode..

Comment: @RahulKumar fine. so check your url link for 2 profiles. if possible share it.

Comment: echo :'<h1><tr><td><a href="3.php?employeecode='.$row["employeecode"].'">'.$row["employeename"].'</a></td></tr></h1>';

Comment: http://localhost/newform1/3.php?employeecode=45678

http://localhost/newform1/3.php?employeecode=323223

Comment: now check your code from where you are picking up your result. check whether it's picking up with exact employeecode. and also check your DB. changed field.

Comment: "Here is my query"

if(isset($_GET["employeecode"])){
 $employeecode=$_GET["employeecode"];

 require_once("dbconfig.php");
 
$query = ("select t1.employeecode,t1.employeename,t1.designation t2.v,t2.w,t2.x,t2.a,t2.b,     t3.total, t3.totals,t3.totalss,t3.netsalary,t3.amount
FROM invoice t1,salaries t2,total1 t3     WHERE t1.employeecode = t2.employeecode AND t2.employeecode = t3.employeecode ORDER by t1.employeecode ASC");  
    
 $result = mysql_query($query,$con);
 if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

Answer (score 0):

it seems your query is not working and fails returning FALSE bool value. To check the reason you need to check your query after dynamically building at run time 
follow below steps

$result = mysql_query($query) or die($query."
".mysql_error());

check the error message. seems some wrong column must be included

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your salaries to be t2..

```
WHERE t1.employeecode = salaries.employeecode AND
```

like

```
WHERE t1.employeecode = t2.employeecode AND
```

I don't know, but what I know when we done give some alias to a table, our dbms would read that alias, not that native table name.